# Analysis of sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, analysis

I have a sharepoint list. I want to do analysis of the data in this list.
Can Power BI of Office365 be used for this ? How can this be done.
Are there any other way to do this ?

Thanks 
Avanti

Answer (score 0):

Since Power BI works with Excel, I would imagine exporting the list to Excel will work just fine for you (keeping in mind that you refresh the data connection in Excel as needed).

Comment: yeah exactly, the reports generated would be static. How can it be done dynamically? As and how the data changes in sharepoint list, the appropriate analysis results must be seen..

Comment: I'll make this a complete statement since I don't know your familiarity with how exported lists work, so I apologize if this sounds patronizing. You'll have to deal with refreshing the link between Excel and SharePoint. It's not hard, you can make a macro that does it whenever you like, but you have to deal with the refresh. It's as dynamic as you make it.

Comment: If you have a server around, you can have that keep the file open and run the refresh macro every hour or something.